# Execute a Stored Procedure Daily

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am building a Web Application which is attached to a Database which is in a Web Server(which is at unknown remote location). I want to execute a Stored Procedure daily at a specific time. I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287060/2914428).

I am able to connect to my Database. But not to Server Agent.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you have access and correct permissions in msdb, then u can use `sp_addjob` to create job using Tsql. Also u can use sqlcmd to schedule it and run on remote server.

Comment: What do you mean you can't connect to SQL Server Agent? Could you be more specific? What edition are you on?

Comment: @Pankaj, are you useing shared DB hosting? it may explain why you don't have access to Agent.

Comment: @g2server yes you are right. Its a shared DB hosting.

Comment: Shared hosting will rarely give you access to SQL Agent, but they may provide other facilities to schedule tasks. Have a look in your hosting control panel for something like that. If you only have SQL Server available, take a look at the solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4079716) (note: this is a more advanced-level solution, so bear that in mind for support reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your DBA has not (and will not) give permissions for SQLServerAgent.
If so you will have to use another scheduler.

If you want to execute a stored procedure daily at a specific time, I'd suggest

- Call the stored procedure from a page in your web application layer
- Set up a scheduler to call the web page at a daily interval.

A free service like this could be set up to call your URL on a daily interval.
http://www.pingjs.com/

Comment: This is the same answer I would give. It's a common solution for situations where you have limited control over the database. Just call the SP from a web page and load that page however often you need it.

Comment: As [Pingjs](http://www.pingjs.com) does not support relative URL. So, I used [Code Effect](http://scheduler.codeeffects.com/) which supports relative URL for Scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

The link in your question applies to MSDE/SQL Express; hopefully your database is on a full SQL Server edition.

If the SQL Server Agent is running on the machine (and you have the required permissions on the *msdb* database), you should see some output from running the stored procedure [`sp_help_jobactivity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), as most installations will have at least one default job. If that works, follow these steps to add a scheduled job using T-SQL:

1. Execute [`sp_add_job`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to create a job.
2. Execute [`sp_add_jobstep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187358%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to create one or more job steps.
3. Execute [`sp_add_schedule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187320%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to create a schedule.
4. Execute [`sp_attach_schedule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to attach a schedule to the job.
5. Execute [`sp_add_jobserver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178625%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to set the server for the job.

Note that values returned or created by one step are required in the next.

Comment: Executed stored procedure 'sp_help_jobactivity', it shows message : Could not find stored procedure 'sp_help_jobactivity'.

Comment: First switch to msdb: `use msdb; go`

Comment: This time it shows message as : The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_help_jobactivity', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: So you unfortunately don't have the required permissions. The other answers are better solutions in this situation - an external scheduled task to either run the stored procedure directly or hit a web page that runs it.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems as though you are dealing with a shared database environment where you have access to neither 1) SQL Server Agent or 2) the hosting OS.

The way I see it, your best bet would be to have a second machine that you have complete control over (i.e. this could be something as simple as a computer you have lying around) and, provided that the machine is running during the time that needs to be scheduled, [create a Windows scheduled task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993.aspx) that kicks off a PowerShell script to run your stored procedure.

This script could look as simple as:

```
$ConnectionString = "data source = ..."

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString)
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "dbo.YourProcName";

# add parameters here if required
#
$SqlCmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ParamName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int) -Property @{ Value = 1234 }))

try {
    $SqlConnection.Open()
    $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
catch {
    # Write-Error $_.Exception
    # you'll want to save this error away 
    # if you are running this as an automated task
}
finally {
    $SqlCmd.Dispose()
    $SqlConnection.Dispose()
}
```

That's just some generalized code (untested), but you should get the general idea.  But as long as you'd have a secondary machine that could serve this functionality, I'd argue that this is the best and easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you dont have permissions on msdb database - so you cant create jobs.

One way would be to use [**SQLCMD**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/) :

```
SQLCMD -SDestinationServer -DDestinationDatabase -UUserName -PStr0ngPassword -Q "exec usp_myproc"
```

put that in a .bat file and schedule it with windows task scheduler else if you have a sql server running that you have proper access, you can schedule that with sql agent.

If you have sql server running with sql agent access, then you can even use linked server to execute SP remotely.

Also, as Thomas mentioned, PowerShell is one option too.